# Putting dataframe Group BY code in a function in R

Tags: r

I have a code in R where I work with multiple dataframes.

Example of a dataframe format :

```
ClientID     Group   CountC   
  X1           A       3
  R3           B       2
  D4           A       1
  T5           A       7
  H0           B       5
```

The other dataframes have the same 2 columns, but `CountC` differs.

For each of the dataframes, I have a common code that calculates quantile by group / and then pivot the form of the dataframe :

```
quantileByGroup <- 
  df %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
      summarize(Q25 = quantile(CountC, probs = .25), 
              Q50 = quantile(CountC, probs = .5),
              Q75 = quantile(CountC, probs = .75),
              Q100 = quantile(CountC, probs = 1))


quantileByGroupFinal <- pivot_longer(quantileByGroup,
                          cols = c(2,3,4,5),
                          names_to = "name",
                          values_to = "value")
```

To avoid repeating the same code everytime, I want to put this code in a function.

However when I try, it is complicated especially for this part :

```
quantileByGroup <- 
  df %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
      summarize(Q25 = quantile(CountC, probs = .25), 
              Q50 = quantile(CountC, probs = .5),
              Q75 = quantile(CountC, probs = .75),
              Q100 = quantile(CountC, probs = 1))
```

Since it is impossible to pass the column names `Group` and `CountC` as parameters in the function.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f <- function(.data, .group, .summarize)
{
  .data %>% 
    dplyr::group_by({{.group}}) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise( "{{.summarize}}_Q25" := quantile({{.summarize}}, probs = .25), 
                      "{{.summarize}}_Q50" := quantile({{.summarize}}, probs = .5),
                      "{{.summarize}}_Q75" := quantile({{.summarize}}, probs = .75),
                      "{{.summarize}}_Q100" := quantile({{.summarize}}, probs = 1)) %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-{{.group}}) %>% 
    return()
}
```

and call like:

```
df %>% 
   f(.group = Group, .summarize = CountC)
```

Comment: I would like to make the "summarize(...)" part dynamic. I am summarizing by a different column that changes from dataframe to another. How can I do that?

Comment: I adapted my answer, you can also checkout: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html